# Binary Search Tree Preorder Traversal

Tags: binary-tree, traversal, binary-search

I have a question regarding preorder traversal of binary search tree. I know what the algorithm has to be like, its pretty simple:

```
void preOrder(Node node) {
    print(node);

    if (node.left() != null)
        preOrder(node.left());
    if (node.right() != null)
        preOrder(node.right());
}
```

For some reason, my function prints out only the left side subtree of the root node, and it prints out the lowest node twice. I ran a `search` method on one of the items on the right side and it returned true so I assume my insertion is working properly. Why is this happening?

My code is below. The public method calls the private one. In the private one, the first two if-statements are there to print the left and right nodes connected to that node. The last two do the actual recursive algorithm.

```
public void print() {

    if (root == null)
        System.out.println("Tree is empty");
    else
        print(root);
}


private void print(NodeBST node) {

        printOut(node);

        if (node.left() != null) {
            System.out.print("Left: ");
            printOut(node.left());
        }

        else
            System.out.println("No left");

        if (node.right() != null) {
            System.out.print("Right: ");
            printOut(node.right());
        }

        else
            System.out.println("No right");

        System.out.println("");

        if (node.left() != null) {
            node = node.left();
            print(node);
        }

        if (node.right() != null) {
            node = node.right();
            print(node);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Which method are you calling when?  preOrder and print both traverse the tree.

Comment: There is no method called `preOrder`. The `printOut` method only prints out the content of the node in the argument. It's basically a `System.out`

Comment: Why are you NOT using the blazingly simple scheme of preOrder?

Comment: What do you mean? This does the very same simple preorder. It just has a bunch of if's for testing print outs. @Stuart just solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well one bug you have is that you overwrite `node` on the line just before the first `print(node)` and then reuse the modified version again straight afterwards. Presumably you want `node` to be the original value when doing the `if(node.right() != null)` test?

You can avoid this by e.g. just calling `print(node.left());` in the first `if`.

Comment: Yep! That was it. Didn't notice it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node *MakeBst(int preOrder[],int str,int end)
{
    struct node *newnode;
    if(str>end)
        return NULL;
    newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(!newnode)
        return NULL;
    if(str == end)
        return newnode;
    newnode->data = preOrder[str];
    str++;
    x = search_Index(number>preOrder[str-1]);
    newnode->left = MAkeBst(preOrder,str,x-1);
    newnode->right = MAkeBst(preOrder,x-1,end);
}
```